# Where do compiler defines (e.g. $CPUX86) get defined? Which folder/file?

Tags: delphi, webbroker

.DLL's produced by Webbroker on my XE8 have stopped working. Browsers get Error 500 regardless of server (Microsoft Server 2011 or Abyss Web Server). .Dll's produced two days ago work fine on both servers.

I installed XE10.1 (I put off the upgrade until now) and precisely the same problem occurs in the simplest of applications. `Result.Content := '<p>Hello world</p>';` crashes.

I am at a loss and am wondering if my compiler's defines have been somehow tampered with. The last thing I did before things stopped working was to try out a IP*Works component and Windows did an update. Nothing else that I can think of.

Comment: None of the predefined compiler defines (CPUX86, WINDOWS, OSX, etc.) are located in a *file or folder*. They're intrinsic to the compiler, based on the target platform. You'll have to look further to find the cause of your issue; this isn't it. Try the debugger.

Comment: I cannot reconcile the question title, and the body. How are they related? I also cannot work out your Delphi versions. I know what XE8 is, but what is XE10.1? There is no such version. You really do need to be precise with details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: XE10.1 is RAD Studio 10 Seattle with Update 1, don't you think?

Comment: @Heartware we might guess that. Better to be precise, don't you think?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In this instance, I believe we already are...

Comment: @Ken Well, there's no such thing as XE10. I imagine we are talking about Delphi 10 Seattle. If the asker used the correct terminology then there'd be no scope for confusion. Imprecision like this is a sign of a confused mind.

Comment: @Ken Please don't start. You were also imprecise. Why is it so hard for people to know what this darn thing is called. It's Delphi 10 Seattle. There is no XE10. Presumably you mean the Delphi 10 Seattle About Box.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why people invent illogical names like 'Delphi 10 Seattle' in the first place? Why users should be blamed for not using these strange names? It is absolutely clear what XE10 is though officially it does not exist.

Comment: @serg I agree the name is silly, but it is what it is. Making up other names doesn't seem very clever. Why XE10? What happened to XE9?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *What happened to XE9?* - I believe the same thing that happened with Windows 9. It is good that they finally removed this *XE* though confusion is quite natural now.

Comment: @serg So if I refer to Windows 10 as Windows 9, you think that's fine?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there is no confusion with 9/10, the confusion is with XE. People say XE10 instead of Delphi 10. Probably they added 'Seattle' to avoid confusion with Delphi 1..7 line, but I believe it makes even more mess. It is not fine.

Comment: @Serg I just don't think it's that hard to know the name and version of your compiler.

Comment: Is there anything in this problem that suggests there might be something wrong with your compiler defines? It seems like you're just taking shots in the dark in your approach to this problem. A more effective approach may be to restore your system from a backup made two or more days ago. You'll have lost two days of progress, but that shouldn't be too bad since those two days of effort weren't working anyway.

Comment: Thank you Ken for the hint about the $DEFINE (s). Yes, my mind is confused - and that is why I need some help from less confused minds, :-)

Comment: Delphi 10.1 is Delphi 10 Seattle update 1. I hope that is clearer. I assumed it was XE10, but it seems their marketing people are keen to earn their keep. To me, Seattle is associated with Microsoft - a bit of a negative.

I feel the same way as DavidHefferman on this topic.

Comment: Rob Kennedy,

Your suggestion - to recover backups - seems to make sense. However, I encountered this same problem with a brand-new, and more recent, version of Delphi. And with the smallest of programs,

Can you please be more specific and let me know which files to restore? Obviously, it cannot be the application itself or the newly installed version of Delphi. 

Perhaps there is something I am missing there. Can you please enlighten us?

Comment: @user1355041: You're welcome. Glad to try and help. I can't be of any more help without seeing code, but I can confidently say that the problem isn't in those defines.

Comment: @David: Don't start what? You disagreed with my comment, and I removed it. I have no idea why EMBT decided on the moronic Delphi 10 Seattle name for the current version. Since the name refers to **Delphi 10**, and as the prior version was **Delphi XE 8**, it's successor might be commonly referred to as **Delphi XE 10** rather than **Delphi 10 Seattle**. As long as everyone knows what's being referenced, I don't see any point in having a pedantic stick up your backside. You clearly feel differently, and that's your right. It's fair in either case to point out that there is no 10.1 of either.

Comment: @Ken "Pedantic stick up your backside". No need. Please don't.

Comment: Though the question was downvoted and seems to be closed soon, it a good question - where the parameters affecting a project's compilation are stored  (in project files *.dpr and *.dproj, in environment variables, in registry, maybe elsewhere).

Comment: Do you have source control?  Can you see what has changed?  If you do not use source control, stop what you are doiing, download it, read about it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of you pointed out - many thanks. :-)

The problem had nothing to do with the compiler defines. Frankly, I don't quite understand what happened. It seems that Delphi 10 update 1 changed my .DPR file and inserted "Web.Win.ISAPIThreadPool"

Simultaneously, it seems, my test server reverted to an older version - heaven knows how that happened and the problem below manifested itself:

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129148

Thank you for helping me regain my sanity and I wish you all the best during this stressful season.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).